# Patch for php 7.2, many deprecated functions

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7.2

I've just installed Magento 1.9.3.10, which contains the patch that supports PHP 7.2.
In Dev mode I get many errors of deprecated functions.
Such as:

```
Deprecated functionality: The each() function is deprecated. This message will be suppressed on further calls  in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend.php on line 79
```

How is this possible? have not all the deprecated features of the core and the used Zend libraries been removed?

How do I use the Developer mode every page is blocked by deprecated functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Deprecated" means removed in a further version or shouldn't be used in favor of another method. So no, these mehtods have not to be removed yet.

You can try this in `index.php` to supress errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
```